# Azure Database Installation Error "Invalid Object name 'Categories' "

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, remote-server, invalid-object-name

I am completely ignorant in relation to databases and servers etc. Please bear with me.

I am trying to install a program called RealProspect 2009 which allows both local and remote sql database installation. Both types are done using the program installation .exe.

I have an azure account on which I have set up a server, and a database. During the program installation I am asked to provide the SQL server address, SQL server name, SQL username and SQL password. Using the information provided in the Azure online tools, I input all of this information into the fields and the program commences installing the database on the remote location. If I use incorrect information in these fields the installation returns an error and tells me it cannot log in, or the IP is not allowed etc., so I know it's actually attempting to connect and verifying the connection credentials.

When I use the correct server and login information the program proceeds. It spends several minutes "Creating the Tables". When it finishes doing that it attempts to begin "Installing Default Data (Categories)". At this point the program stops and I get the error in the subject line of this post "Invalid Object name 'Categories' "

I don't know enough to tell you what I don't know about this process.

I just signed up for Azure specifically because hosting the database with Azure is like $5-10 per month and I want myself and several other participants to be able to use the software with a common database. I created the server and database using the gui "tools/how to" from within the online Azure portal and I have never written a script, or accessed the server/database using anything other than the online GUI.

Thank you in advance for any help you may be able to provide. I hope i'm not too much of a speed bump to your day.

P.S. - For what it's worth you can download a free trial of the software from realinvestorsoftware.com and see if you could install it on a remote server. Maybe you can better see what I see and tell me how to do it on my own?

Comment: i sent a support ticket to the developer of the software.  Here was his response "Its the default installation of MSSQL Server 2005.  The user has dbowner access to the DB.  That's it.  I'm not sure what your Azure is all about, but the connection string you want to use is the ADO.NET.  Here is an example of the connection strings I use...

Server=SERVERNAME;Database=DATABASENAME;Persist Security Info=False;UID=USERNAME;PWD=PASSWORD;pooling='true'  

The latin coalition  should be fine, just choose that first one. Im not really sure about the other settings."

Answer (score 0):

SQL Azure is VERY similar to SQL Server but there are [a few features that SQL Azure doesn't support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff394115.aspx). That said, I'd be surprised if the app's installer is using any of the features that are unsupported by SQL Azure. My guess is that there's a bug in their installation scripts that might fail on more modern versions of SQL Server (note, their app installs on [SQL Express 2005 which is no longer in mainstream support](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/default.aspx?sort=PN&alpha=SQL+Server+2005+Express&Filter=FilterNO)).

Just a couple of other thoughts for you: You get keys to install the app on two machines but:

> "If you would like to install on more than two computers, then after you order your copy of RealProspect you can login to your customer account on this website and order additional activation keys for only $97 each."

Because you're going to be paying several hundred dollars anyway, and because (you yourself admit) you're not a database expert, it may be less cost, stress and hard-work to use their $27 per month database hosting service. That way you can concentrate on building your business while they take care of the technology.

> [Update: 3/27/2013 @ 23:05]
>   Another option Chris presented was to install the app and database locally and then migrate the database to Azure.

While this is potentially feasible, it requires some finesse to execute.

[Microsoft provides a DB migration guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee730904.aspx) presenting several (pretty manual) options.

You might also want to read [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ssdsgetstarted/thread/c635f2df-89bb-48b5-95ac-e2de7fed95d7) which discusses how to migrate your DB via a DACPack.

Another option is to download and use the [SQL Azure Migration Wizard](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/) which should do most of the heavy-lifting for you and make your DB migration simpler.

However, note that it is possible that the DB the app uses *may* use features of SQL Server that are not supported on SQL Azure. Hopefully this isn't the case, but be aware that this may be an issue.

Good luck :)

Comment: "My guess is that there's a bug in their installation scripts that might fail on more modern versions of SQL Server (note, their app installs on SQL Express 2005 which is no longer in mainstream support)."  I agree that this may be an issue.  And your other thought are very correct, and to the point.  However, i've been burned keeping all my eggs in one basket before and would prefer for peace of mind to maintain the DB where i have control if at all possible.  That being said, if there is no feasible way for me to do this i'll admit defeat and host with them.

Comment: I can install a completely local copy of the software and database.  Would having all of the original sql files locally on my machine in any way help me to transfer them to the Azure server/DB ?  I can also, through the RP software, create a backup of the DB to a zip file which contains a tables.sql, and about 8 xml files.  I tried installing and opening SQL Server Data tools, and Visual Studio shell, in an effort to export a BACPAC file and follow the instructions for importing that to Azure, but i'm pretty lost because i don't know what to "open" in the installation folders or the backup zip

Comment: Also, thank you very much!!!! for researching the issue enough to give me a well thought out response that involved the cost of hosting and the cost of the software as well.  Very kind of you!

Comment: Hey Chris. Glad you found my reply useful. I've added some more guidance above regarding migration. While I can understand your reticence, if you're not pretty well-versed in DB technology, you may end up with more work than is worth it, especially when it comes to backing-up your data, etc. On the other hand, it's fun stuff to learn ;)

Answer (score 0):

Chris,

I think SQL Database Migration Wizard v3.9.10 & v4.0.13 will solve your problem, I have used this tool several time to migrate db from local machine to sql azure, the most beauty of this tool it also highlights the error or sql which couldn't be migrated to Azure, so we can easily find alternate syntax of such sql queries